# Flagging a comment doesn't count as a review

Tags: support, comments, review, comment-flags, comment-voting

While reviewing **First Posts** or **Late Answers** if you upvote a comment, it counts as "reviewed".

If you flag a comment (for any reason) it doesn't count.

Is this intentional? Any particular reason behind it?